# Vauxhall Viva clutch slipping - does it need the work that's being quoted?

Tags: vauxhall

Hi I have a Vauxhall Viva which I purchased new in Dec 2015. I have just had to put it in a garage because the clutch is slipping.
 Now I am not a mechanic so excuse the way I describe this.... yesterday the rev counter went right up, the engine sounded like it was revving but there was no extra speed, I was only doing 30, when I took foot off accelerator the car shuddered, I put foot back on and it was ok.  It happened twice in 15 mins.  This morning I was sat in traffic, stopped at lights put it in first gear lifted clutch thats when there was grinding noise.  It only happened in first, but it did it a few times.  So I called garage and took it in.  I have only had it just over a year abd like I said its only done 7000 miles.  I am not a boy racer I drive carefully.

It obviously needs replacing but I just want to know if it covered under warranty.  It is with Thurlow Nunn which is where I purchased it.

They tell me it needs new clutch and therefore the gearbox needs removing. They also said slave needs replacing. They are not sure if it will be covered under warranty and are quoting me £1200 to repair. Car has only done 7000 miles and I am the only driver (and a careful driver).

Does this sound right? Could it be dodgy gearbox or is the garage pulling a fast one? Surely it should be covered under warranty.

Comment: Unless there is blatant trauma to the clutch, the manufacturer should be covering all of this. IIRC, Vauxhall is a GM company. GM, just like all the other major manufacturers, stands behind their warranties. They should be paying to have the clutch/slave replaced. It won't cost the garage a dime as long as they are a Vauxhall authorized repair agent. Unless you are hot rodding your Vauxhall, there is no way to have worn out a clutch in 7k miles. It should last 100k+. If your Vauxhall garage won't fix it under warranty, ask to speak to the manager. If they say no, take it over their head.

Comment: Sounds about right for the repair costs, but not right for the longevity of the clutch. Two possibilities: (1) you rest your foot on the clutch pedal and clutch is therefore slipping continuously, (2) something in the car is broken / has failed. Obviously the clutch has failed, but did it fail on its own or is there something that causes the clutch to slip continuously? If (1) isn't true, I would demand them to find the real root cause of the problem.

Comment: No never rest foot on clutch, learnt to drive 35 years ago and was taught to always take foot right off clutch and put flat on floor.  So guess they  will need to check it thoroughly.  It did rev a couple of times with no extra speed, then shuddered when I took foot of accelerator and theb this morning when it was in first I lifted foot off clutch and there was grinding noise.  Thats when I took it to garage.

Comment: I'm worried about the grinding noise. Could you edit your question and add very detailed description of what you observed before taking it to the garage, as based on your comment you probably know more than what you said in the original question? The grinding noise could indicate gearbox failure.

Answer (score 1):

As Paulster said in the comments, this should *probably* be covered under warranty.  I can't find the Vauxhall one word for word, but [GMC](http://www.gmc.com/owners/warranty-details.html)'s Warranty info suggests that the slave cylinder (the thing that makes the clutch move in and out when you press the pedal) is covered, but the clutch is not.

If the Vauxhall warranty is the same as the GMC one (which is probable since they are both part of General Motors), you should probably be ok.  It is almost a certainty that the slave cylinder failure caused the clutch damage.  If you had the car serviced somewhat recently before this happened, then you should be alright on the "improper maintenance" clause.  If they didn't agree with this and warranty the clutch for you, I would be mildly surprised.  If you took it over the head of whoever you were talking too and they didn't honor the warranty, I would be highly surprised.*

*assuming Vauxhall and GMC have similar warranty condiditions.  That said, I don't live in England/Australia so things may be different over there.

Answer (score 1):

Vauxhall warranty is found at http://www.vauxhall.co.uk/owners_services/warranty_assistance/index.html

Reading it, it says that the clutch plate is not covered, because it is a consumable; but I would be calling Vauxhall and asking for their reading on the situation *before* giving any go-ahead to the stealership. Normally I'd say that you're out of luck, but 7,000 miles only sounds like there is a defect in there.

Answer (score 0):

Now this would depend on the country your in any EU country has a fit for purpose clause in law on all parts like that are ware and tare or not. the fact you have been running this car for less than 3 years a clutch should not go unless you have been destroying it by dropping it very fast. if the damage was caused by another part that was not fit for purpose in this case a substandard slave they are responsible for refunding for the damage to other parts in this case replacing your clutch.

but a verification on what they have said needs doing, when replacing a clutch,

- gear box does have to be removed / disconnected so they can access
  clutch.
- Slave is dodgy they have to replace that under warranty.
- When replacing a clutch plate the release baring should be replaced.

i noted that last one as you don't seem to have been quoted for it but it is a ware and tear part not covered under warranty and should be replaced whenever a clutch plate is replaced.

Just as another note that this is not standard ware and tear is that a clutch should give you another 1000 miles when diven with care once it starts slipping before getting to the point of damaging other things.